# How to access a hash in the main namespace from inside a module

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I have my main Perl script which contains

```
my $System = {
    Path =>
    {
        root => 'hello'
    }
}

print $System->{'Path'}->{'root'}; # prints 'hello'
```

How can I access the `$System->{'Path'}->{'root'}` variable from an external module?

I know I can use the `main::` namespace to retrieve global variables, such as `$main::x`, but the following doesn't work `$main::System->{'Path'}->{'root'}`.

I tried also different syntaxes but I'm not able to get it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lexical (`my`) variables do not exist in any <strike>namespace</strike>package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared with `my` only have lexical scope and are not visible in a package.

Declare it with `our` instead.

Comment: Will it change something in my actual main script if I declare the variable that way?

Comment: Yes, the scope is widened so the behaviour is different. It could lead to bugs. Do not just change the line, make an effort to understand where the identifier `$System` is valid and do test your program.

Answer (score 1):

"Coping with Scoping":

```
  http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html
```